# SharePoint 2007 unable to display pdf icon in old content

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, ifilter, multiline-text-field

I've an issue on display pdf icon in SharePoint 2007, pdf icon should be display on the hyperlink created in Rich Text Editor.

I tried to add the pdf icon (downloaded from adobe http://www.adobe.com/misc/linking.html), then moved the icon into Template/IMAGES folder, and then add new extension tag in Template/XML/DOCICON.xml  (e.g: ). After that perform iisreset.

After perform the actions above, now I able to view the pdf icon in hyperlink and also in Document Library. However, the old content (hyperlink in RTE) still not able to display pdf icon, how can I solve this?

Perhaps like install ifilter or something...

Please help, thank you in advanced.

Comment: what do you mean by pdf icon in rich text editor? Are you create Content Editor Web Part and fill it with URL/link that pointed to your icon(_Images/pdf.ico)?

Comment: No, there is a Site Column (multiline of text) in the page layout, so that I can add in the hyperlink via the RTE tool bar